# prevent execution of line of code before function invocation

Tags: javascript, push-notification, promise

I am working on Push Notification API and I am stumbling on a problem with javascript execution.

I have this function as follows:

```
 function subscribeUserToPush() {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging.js')
        .then(function (registration) {
            const subscribeOptions = {
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array('BEjboIY283xz3XTcjiFGVBGWazp20_LArGgplbQw0h91bafKBIT2zl7BSKZBgOV9tg1Tb_X0BXxrB1BjxX6WZvQ')
            };
            return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
        })
        .then(function (pushSubscription) {
            console.log('Received PushSubscription: ', JSON.stringify(pushSubscription));
            const subscriptionObject = JSON.stringify(pushSubscription);
            subscription = subscriptionObject;
            console.log('EndPoint url: ', pushSubscription.endpoint);
            return pushSubscription;

        });

}

subscribeUserToPush();
```

After calling this function I should have the value in the following variables:

```
console.log('Global scope subscription', window.subscription);
var endpoint = window.subscription.endpoint;
    var key = window.subscription.getKey('p256dh');
    var auth = window.subscription.getKey('auth');
```

> However, in my console: I first see Global scope subscription
>   undefined and an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'endpoint' of undefined

In the debugger although, window.subscription gets the updated value.
Can anyone help me with this issue. I am new to working with promises and web push notification api. I want to use the avove variable for my ajax call to send the subscription info to the server.

Comment: `navigator.serviceWorker.register` is an asynchronous method, meaning it runs in the background (generally due to requiring a network call) Your main thread will continue execution, even though it hasn't executed all the code that is *written* before.  You could move the code that is going to require `endpoint` be set into the .then() block, or you could use something like async/await if you're using node.

Comment: That makes it clear why it first executes the console.log. However, what should I do if I want to use the value of subscription in a later function using the endpoint, key etc. I am using just plain javascript and not node. So what would be my options? If there is any.

Comment: Cache the *promise* returned by `subscribeUserToPush()`, not the result delivered by the promise. Wherever necessary, access `subscription` from the cached promise via its `.then()` method.

Comment: I do not understand it really well. i will try to do it and update if it worked. Thanks

Comment: I had to basically use a the endpoint value in a different function so I actually called my function inside the subscribeUserToPush function and it worked. Thanks for your input guys. It helped me with understanding some stuff.